# Does the earth exert centrifugal force on us in air?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, earth, air, centrifugal-force

Whether the centrifugal force exerted by earth due to rotation be felt or even applied to us if we were in air ? The landmass rotates with earth so it is exerted on us radially outwards , but that isn't the case with air because we have wind speeds on opposite direction of earth too!

Comment: If you're in a rotating frame, there is a centrifugal force. If you're moving with the wind, there is a non-zero Coriolis force...so perhaps your question needs to be more specific?

Comment: lets say im free falling , now what would be the outcome @JEB ? , main thing is how well does air communicate the centrifugal force of land below or does it not communicate because it is moving sometimes in opposite direction too ?

Comment: If you're working in Earth Centered Earth Fixed (ECEF) coordinates, or geodetic coordinates, there is a centrifugal force (and if you are falling, there will be a Coriolis force). If you're working in any of the Earth Centered Inertial (ECI) frames, then no, there is no centrifugal force.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments under your question, whether or not you need to take account of centrifugal force (and/or Coriolis force) depends solely on whether you are using co-ordinates relative to a [rotating reference frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_reference_frame) or an [inertial reference frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertial_frame_of_reference). There is no need for centrifugal force to be "communicated" through the air.

If you are on a rotating roundabout (and you are measuring your position relative to the roundabout) and you jump up in the air, centrifugal force does not go away just because you are no longer in contact with the roundabout. Of course, if you measure your position relative to the ground, there is no centrifugal force in either case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , then another question that ponders is how is air not affected by centrifugal force ?

Comment: In the rotating reference frame air is affected by the centrifugal force. **Everything** is affected by centrifugal force in the rotating frame

Comment: that makes sense , then air  must have a greater force due to pressure I think for this to happen ! @Dale

Comment: But no matter what coordinate system you use, the centrifugal force is not "exerted by the earth". Or by anything else.

Comment: sorry for my wording there @nasu  , yes it is a fundamental property of an object subject to rotation i think

Comment: @Razz No, centrifugal force is not a property of an object. It is an artefact produced by measuring co-ordinates relative to a rotating reference frame. If you measure co-ordinates relative to an inertial reference frame than there is no centrifugal force. Same objects, different forces.

Comment: oh , thank you @gandalf61